# Smartedit not working with Spartacus in ccv2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Smartedit stop to work with Spartacus at CCv2 environments.

If I try to load Spartacus storefront in response I can see next headers:

> X-Frame-Options: DENY
>
> X-Powered-By: Express

Before everything works ok, probably now somewhere added 'X-Frame-Options' header

Is there anything new that need to be configured to be able to use Smartedit again?

Comment: Ok, probably find out why it happens(https://me.sap.com/notes/3334671/E). But still would like to see somewhere a proper solution...